# Selector issue using a loop in jQuery

Tags: jquery, for-loop, jquery-selectors

In my jQuery code (see below), I can't manage to change the color of the "typetravaux" class content.
The opacity change on hover is OK, but the color change does not work (I tried 2 different ways, but none of them is working).

Can you guys tell me what I am doing wrong ? Thanks !

**CSS :**

```css
.typetravaux {
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="solutions">
    <div class="bloc1">
      <span class="typetravaux">PLOMBERIE</span>
       <div class="picture"><img src="img/plomberie.png" class="prestapicture"></div>
     </div>
    <div class="bloc2">
      <span class="typetravaux">CHAUFFAGE</span>
       <div class="picture"><img src="img/chauffage.jpg" class="prestapicture"></div>
     </div>
    <div class="bloc3">
      <span class="typetravaux">CLIMATISATION</span>
       <div class="picture"><img src="img/climatisation.jpg" class="prestapicture"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```javascript
$prestapicture = $('.prestapicture');

for (y=0; y < $prestapicture.length; y++) {
    $prestapicture.eq(y).on("mouseover", function() {
      $(this).css("opacity", "0.3");
      $(this).prev(".typetravaux").css("color","black") // **does not work**
    
    })
    
    $prestapicture.eq(y).on("mouseout", function() {
      $(this).css("opacity", "1");
      $(".typetravaux").eq(y).css("color","white"); //**does not work either**
    
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`prev` uses the previous **sibling**, but the `.typetravaux` elements aren't siblings of the `.prestapicture` elements, they're siblings of those elements' parent `.picture` elements.

You *could* fix that like this:

```
$(this).parent().prev(".typetravaux").css("color","black");
//      ^^^^^^^^^
```

...but it's quite fragile, minor changes to the HTML break it.

Instead, I'd either:

1. Add a class to the container div and do this:

   ```javascript
   $(this).closest(".container").find(".typetravaux").css("color","black");
   ```

   or
2. Add a class to that container for when you want this different styling, and use a descendant combinator (a space) in CSS to do the CSS changes.

   ```javascript
   .pic-hovered .typetravaux {
       color: black;
   }
   ```

---

In general, I would avoid using `css()` for styling. Use classes, and put the style rules in your CSS.